# Is there any open-source web browser app available for Symbian?

Tags: open-source, browser, symbian

I want to know **weather there are any open-source web browser apps available for Symbian platform?**

(I searched about this everywhere but got nothing)

Here is my case:

I successfully developed a [web browser](http://www.dhablog.co.cc/2011/01/read-sinhalatamil-webpages-conveniently.html) for Android which is capable of rendering Sinhala/Tamil complex script web text. For that I used an open-source web browser available for Android & added the functionality to render the complex scripts. After I published that app, I'm getting so many requests to develop that browser for Symbian also since most of the Sinhalese & Tamils use Symbian Nokia phones. So in order to implement the rendering engine I developed, I'm searching weather there are any open-source web browser apps available for Symbian. Otherwise I'll have to develop a whole web browser with rendering capability.

Please share your ideas on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Opera works great on my Symbian phone. Can you write an extension for that?

Answer (score 0):

For example, [webkit](http://webkit.org/) is open source and has been ported to Symbian. The native S60 browser uses it as well. To get started with using it, consider [QtWebKit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtwebkit.html) as your browser engine. Adding UI controls on top of it is relatively straightforward, at least compared to writing a browser from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no open source browser available for Symbian.

Nokia has however released their port of WebKit to Symbian as open source, you might consider using that.